# Formatting Netlogo code using Minted

Tags: netlogo, pygments

I don't suppose anyone has created a lexer for the Pygments package for Netlogo and would be willing to share it?

[write your own lexer](http://pygments.org/docs/lexerdevelopment/)

It's not something I have the skills to do but having formatted code from other languages in Latex using the Minted package (which in turn uses Pygments), it is extremely useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, someone *has* created a lexer!

http://netlogo-pygment.sourceforge.net/

I have a vague recollection of having to fiddle with the installation a bit when I first used it, but it's been working ever since and I use it with Minted to format all my NetLogo code in documents.

Comment: To make it work, I had to change `aliases = ['NetLogo']` to `aliases = ['nlogo']` in `__init__.py`. Not 100% sure, but I suspect that pygments doesn't like the uppercase characters in the lexer alias.